# Trigger an action when attaching file to Media Library

Tags: media-library

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1. I have a scenario in which i want to trigger an action when a file is uploaded to the media library and trigger another action when i re attach a file to the previously uploaded file. 
I was able to customize the "uiUpload Processor" in order to trigger the first action when a file is uploaded.

[image]

Is there a similar way to customize the "attach" action??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom processor for `attachFile` pipeline. Create a patch file like below -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <processors>
      <attachFile>
         //Add the patch:before type where you want to add your procesor
        <processor type="xyz.foundation.className,xyz.foundation" mode="on" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Attach.CheckSize,Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
      </attachFile>
    </processors>
  <sitecore>
</configuration>
```

and code can be like this with pipeline arguments will be `AttachArgs`, make sure to include `Sitecore.Pipelines.Attach` namespace in class -

```
public class className
{
    public void Process(AttachArgs args)
    {
        //Some condition
        if (args.MediaItem.Title != "test")
        {
            //Some action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for helping. Yes this worked with me (Y)

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while, if I am remembering correctly attach action will run the following pipeline you could potentially extend.

```
<attachFile argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.Attach.AttachArgs">
</attachFile>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i was looking for.